# I created my own crypto coin. Do I have to keep my node running all the time?

Tags: altcoin

I created my own crypto coin.  I have two questions:

1. Do I have to keep my node running all the time?
2. Is it better to have more than one node running?

Answer (score 1):

You really should not be using your own altcoin if you don't know the answers to these questions.  If you just want to experiment, you're welcome to use [Bitcoin's testnet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Testnet) or [regtest mode](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#regtest-mode).  However, here are the answers anyway:

1. *Somebody* has to keep a node running all the time or new users of your altcoin won't be able to download its block chain.
2. The more nodes you have running (on different computers), the more capacity your altcoin will have to grow its userbase.  By default, each Bitcoin Core node can handle 125 connections (normally 8 of which will be outbound).  I assume you didn't change that part of the code, so unless you expect more than about 100 users to suddenly start using your altcoin, running one node should be sufficient.

Again, running an altcoin is not something a newbie should be doing.